# Link between Extended Supergauge Group and Twistor Theory

Tags: mp.mathematical-physics, supersymmetry

In a 1974 paper on [supergauge transformations in four dimensions](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/0550321374903551), Wess and Zumino considered an extended supergauge group which contains the conformal group as a subgroup.  An interesting thing about this supergauge group is that the group generators seem to be quantum analogues of what are known elsewhere as [twistors](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0370157373900082).

Has this link ever been clearly explored in more detail in the meantime?  I am aware that there has also been a [supersymmetric version](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/0550321378902572?via%3Dihub) of twistor theory which establishes something resembling a suitable supersymmetric extension of classical twistor theory (also in the 1970s).